# What is this old brass item?

Tags: tool-identification

This was in my grandfather's tool chest and probably dates back to the 1920's or earlier.  It does not have any markings on it.  It is made of brass and approximately 4 inches long. Notice that one edge of the arm is straight while the other side is curved. The gap between the tines is 3/16 inch or 5 millimeters.

[image]

Comment: Where are the use-marks and scratches? I don't know what the tool is but finding the small marks of use will give valuable clues. If the marks are on the tips, then maybe it was used to tighten saw handles with split nuts (like https://i2.wp.com/benchblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/JMW9030.jpg) or if the marks are on the inside maybe it is wrench of some sort. Let us know what you see.

Comment: It looks somewhat like a large and ungainly golfer's divot repair tool. It may not be a tool at all. It may be part of a larger assembly such as a lever arm or decorative piece though it lacks much in the way of apparent positive attachment points. It's dainty tapering shape and being made of brass or some bronze alloy mean that not too much can be reasonably demanded of it as far as mechanical stress on the forked end. If it were some high strength beryllium bronze alloy then it could conceivably be something like a combination wrench/leverage tool and non-marring striking tool.

Comment: I don't believe beryllium was available at any reasonable price in that time period. It is still a very expensive alloy. Interested in seeing photos of scratches as well.

Answer (score -4):

It's a collet wrench for a Bosch router of that time period

Comment: Hi JimBob.  I can see that as a possibility.  Do you know where I can find a photo of a Bosch router from that era to see how this item might work with it?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have anything to back that up? Why would it be so different from a simple 5mm wrench? (cylinder on the back, odd-shaped lever, brass).